# how to use selenium grid with Specflow and Nunit and Webdriver (in DotNet version)

Tags: selenium, nunit, specflow

Presently we built a Automation framework which uses Selenium Webdriver+ specflow + Nunit, and we suing bamboo as our CI to run our Job against our every build.

we written a build.xml to handle our targets (like clean, init, install latest build, run Selenium scripts, uninstall build. etc)

ant command will read the tag name from the build.xml and runs the respective feature/scenarios based on Tags (like @smoke, @Regression)with Nunit in CI machine.

Now our requirement is to use Selenium Grid to divide scripts into different machine and execute with above set-up. Grid has to divide the scripts based on feature file or based on Tags.How to achieve this.

Is there any thing need to done under [BeforeFeature] and [BeforeScenario] ?

If you provide in details steps or any link which explains detail steps that would be a great help.

Please any one can help in this regards.

Thanks,
Ashok

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood the role Grid plays in distributed parallel testing. It does not "divide the scripts", but simply provides a single hub resource through which multiple tests can open concurrent sessions.

It is the role of the test runner (in your case Specflow) to divide tests and start multiple threads.

I believe that you require SpecFlow+ (http://www.specflow.org/plus/), but this does have a license cost.

It should be possible to create your own multithread test runner for Specflow but will require programming and technical knowledge.

If you want a free open source approach to parallel test execution in DotNet, then there is MbUnit (http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit)  but this would require you to rewrite your tests